# More elegant way using inheritance (with abstract classes) to provide subclasses with a subsection of methods within a custom framework?

Tags: java, c#, inheritance, abstract

I have following exemplary setup:

[image: Class diagram of setup]

Unfortunately, this won't work and I can't find a proper, elegant workaround.
The idea is, when adding a new animal category (e.g. birds), I just create a TemplateBird similar to TemplateMammals. When creating a new bird class, I will have only access to the proper methods, defined via class BirdStuff.

I can create a non-abstract methods in the animal category templates (e.g.

```
public MammalStuff getAnimalStuff{ return new MammalStuff()}
```

for TemplateMammals) but I don't like this, since I want to create a Framework and thus want to force the user to implement such a method.

Have you any idea for an elegant improvement? Or a complete other idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using generics?

### AnimalStuff

In first step, we'll have the stuff defined and the `Stuff` must derive from a base `Interface` or `Abstract class`:

```
public interface AnimalStuff{
    public void doAnimal();
}
```

Then you'll define your hierarchy as you want. I mixed abstract classes and interface but you can do full abstract classes or full interface until the implemented classes:

```
public abstract class MammalStuff implements AnimalStuff{
    // no need to override unless there are mammal specific stuff
    public void doAnimal(){...}
}

public abstract class BirdStuff implements AnimalStuff{
    // example of bird specific
    @Override
    public void doAnimal(){
        System.out.println("I believe I can fly!!!");
    }
}
```

If I follow the exemple of a bird:

```
public class EagleStuff extends BirdStuff{

    @Override
    public void doAnimal(){
        super.doAnimal();
        System.out.println("But I also eat preys!!!");
    }

}
```

### Animal classes

Then you can create your Animals hierarchy:

```
public abstract class TemplateAnimal<S extends AnimalStuff> {

    public abstract S getAnimalStuff();

}
```

With the hierarchy you defined. The generics definition is valid here **because** `MammalStuff` and `BirdStuff` extends (or implements) `AnimalStuff`

```
public abstract class TemplateMammal<S extends MammalStuff> extends TemplateAnimal<S>{

    // no overriding here
    // public abstract S getAnimalStuff();
}

public abstract class TemplateBird<S extends BirdStuff> extends TemplateAnimal<S>{

    // no overriding here
    // public abstract S getAnimalStuff();
}
```

Then, you'll have your Eagle:

```
public class Eagle extends TemplateBird<EagleStuff>{

    @Override
    public EagleStuff getAnimalStuff(){
        // return ...
    }

}
```

In the `Eagle` class, in you have the `getAnimalStuff()` with this signature `public AnimalStuff getAnimalStuff()`, it is illegal because the generic requires to return `S` type, not an `AnimalStuff`

Comment: Thank you too for your detailed explanation. It helps!

Comment: You're welcomed! I just realised that you also tagged `C#`. I can only help you in Java. One last comment when playing with generics: be careful about initialisation (like how do you initialise `BirdStuff` or `EagleStuff`) and your constructor scope

Comment: It is not needed to override the getAnimalStuff unless you want to do something else in the getter method. The benefit of the generic is to have type-safety when you _call_ getAnimalStuff() on an instance Eagle by an external class: EagleStuff stuff = new Eagle().getAnimalStuff();

Comment: @Heri : true, the overriding is not mandatory. Thanks for pointing this out. Well, it greatly depends on the design :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic which is constrained to AnimalStuff.

```
public class Dog : TemplateMammals
{
    public void SomethingWhereINeedStuff()
    {
        var stuff = GetAnimalStuff();
        // stuff is of type MammalsStuff
    }
}

public class TempalteMammals : TemplateAnimals<MammalsStuff>
{
    public abstract MammalsStuff GetAnimalStuff() { ... }
}

public class TemplateAnimals<TStuff> where TStuff : AnimalStuff 
{
    public abstract TStuff GetAnimalStuff();
}
```

Comment: I had generics in my mind, but couldn't figure out a good way to solve that. Your idea is promising, I'll try it. Thank you!